# Find Equilibrium Constant with only balanced equation?

Tags: equilibrium, gas-laws, pressure

> Calculate the value of $K_p$ for the following equation:
>
> $$\ce{PCl3 (g) + Cl2 (g) <=> PCl5 (g)} ,\qquad \mathrm{R = 0.0821 \frac{L\times atm}{mol\times K}}$$

This question appeared on my test. I know how to find $K_p$ if I was given $K_c$ $(K_{\mathrm{p}} = K_\mathrm{c} \times (\mathrm{R} \times T)^{n})$ or if I was given the partial pressures of all of the parts at equilibrium, but none of those values were given; only the equation. My professor marked the answer as $0.041$ (no units), but I have no idea how to calculate that if I wasn't given any values.

Comment: Notice that I replaced `\mathrm` with `\ce` for your _chemical equation_. Just like that, it properly rendered the subscripts and reaction arrows!

Comment: Interesting that the answer is 1/2 of R, and that there 1/2 as many moles of gas on the right side of the equation.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Interesting observation. I wonder if my professor accidentally took the moles of each side and divided them (products/reactants) instead of using the partial pressures.

Comment: Were you given _any_ other information at all for the problem? I think the key is that the total _pressure_ of the products is half of the total pressure of the reactants if the volume is constant.

Comment: I have the test in front of me, and there's absolutely nothing else in the question. If my professor was thinking about the total pressure of each side, I don't see how R would be involved in the equation to begin with.

Comment: Were you allowed to use tables of free energies of formation or enthalpies and  entropies of formation?

Comment: The only attached information that we were given was the periodic table